# Why am I not getting power to outside outlet?

Tags: receptacle, power

Not getting power to outside outlet but have one outlet that has power on the outside checked the breaker it has not been tripped don't know what to do.

How do I fix it to work again? Maybe one month ago I had power, now only my front of the house works and back outside plug don't work both run on same breaker.

Comment: How  do I fix it to work again may be one month ago had power now only my front of the house works and back out side plug don't  work both run on same breaker..

Answer (score 5):

An outside outlet either *is* a GFCI receptacle or it's protected by an upstream GFCI receptacle.  For instance, the outlets on the outside of my house are protected by a GFCI outlet in my garage, so they're not even near each other.  Find, test and reset all the GFCI outlets in the house and see if that restores power.

Comment: You're assuming all installations follow current code, which is not true; code didn't always specify this, and even after it had people did the wrong thing. (My 1962 house had a non-GFI outlet on the porch.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with JPhi1618. However, outlets do also go bad depending on their quality & heavy usage, even & especially GFCI ones. An electrician can pop-in new ones very quickly & assess the circuit for defects or weak points.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the fuse box? If the fuse is not flipped, run a continuity test. Rats have been known to gnaw through wiring. Hopefully the problem is merely a tripped switch in the main fuse box.

I would also shut the power off, unscrew the plate, pull out the outlet, turn the power back on and carefully use a voltmeter to see if the black wire is hot (the other lead of your meter to ground). If the black wire is hot, reading 115 to 120 V, then the outlet needs to be replaced, a cheap and easy job.

BTW, don't assume the black wire is hot. People make mistakes. The contractor may have incorrectly used a white wire as the line.

Good luck...and be careful.